# HTML select box with blank to be displayed until you select any of them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, select

Imagine a select HTML element below:

```
<select id="mySelect">
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Orange</option>
  <option>Pineapple</option>
  <option>Banana</option>
</select>
```

I want that when this DOM element is rendered, the selected value should be blank and not either of 4 fruits.
I do not want to include blank as another option.
Is it possible?

That is I do not want to add another item like:

```
<select id="mySelect">
  <option>Select an item </option>
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Orange</option>
  <option>Pineapple</option>
  <option>Banana</option>
</select>
```

OR

```
<select id="mySelect">
 <option></option>
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Orange</option>
  <option>Pineapple</option>
  <option>Banana</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will work fine for you

Use this HTML

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option>Apple</option>
    <option>Orange</option>
    <option>Pineapple</option>
    <option>Banana</option>
</select>
```

And in jQuery use

```
$('#mySelect').prop('selectedIndex', -1);
```

Javascript version (tested on lastest chrome, firefox & IE 11)

```
document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex = -1
```

this should make the drop down list display blank without adding an extra blank option to the list

Comment: The question was purely for HTML and this answer does not suffice the OP's request.

Comment: No offense :). It's just common on StackOverflow that people tend to offer solutions with techniques that are not requested, or not in the tags. It's better to ask the OP in a comment if he/she wants to use JS/jQuery. In this case it seems the OP wanted to know if it was possible purely by HTML code. Furthermore; your answer makes perfect sense, nothing wrong with that :)

Comment: Thanx, i will try out your tip next time.

Comment: Thank you for the help..I really appreciate it :-) However, I cannot use jQuery here. Either pure javascript or HTML..that is it.  :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this with plain HTML. Check the MDN and official W3C HTML5.x nightly build:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/select
- http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#the-select-element

You really need to switch it out with JavaScript and using the selected attribute on a "fake" option.

These are the availabilities of attributes (properties) of the `<select>` element:

***Global***

accesskey class contenteditable contextmenu dir draggable dropzone hidden id inert spellcheck style tabindex title translate

***Select***

autofocus disabled form multiple name required size

### Update

As the OP seemed to allow JavaScript as an alternative, but not jQuery I've added a plain JavaScript example to prepend a empty (selected) option tag;

```
var fakeOpt = document.createElement('option');
var myList = document.getElementById('mySelect');

fakeOpt.selected = 'selected';
myList.insertBefore(fakeOpt, myList[0]);

// Listen to a change
myList.onchange = function(evt){
    var clicked_option = myList.options[myList.selectedIndex].text;

    if (clicked_option.trim() != '') {
        console.log(clicked_option);
    }
    else {
        console.log('Empty option selected');
    }
};
```

With this there is no need to fill in one by hand in the HTML code.

Here's a JSfiddle; http://jsfiddle.net/VjCbE/3/

Comment: I cannot use fake option because otherwise user can select that and that is what i dont want :(

Comment: @user1751865 I've added a pure JavaScript example. Good luck!

Comment: This example still have the same issue. What i want is that the select box should be blank initially and the user should only be able to choose among the four fruits and user should NOT be able to choose the blank option

Comment: I wonder; if you do any research yourself? With some logic it's not that hard at all to remove the empty option element again once the user has selected one of the valid options. You still have to notify the user (on submit) if a valid option is selected.

Answer (score 3):

I just found a very pretty solution:

```
<pre>
<label for="hardness">Select the hardness</label> : 
    <select name="hardness" id="hardness">
        <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled"></option>
        <option value="3">Easy</option>
        <option value="6">Medium</option>
        <option value="10">Hard</option>
    </select>
</pre>
```

Now selectHardness.selectedIndex always > 0;

Answer (score 2):

```
<option selected disabled value=''></option>
```

`selected` makes this option the default one.
`disabled` makes this option unclickable.